# Swift: How to Read JSON Data from JSON Data

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have read some data from JSON, which include a url of another JSON file, I need to read that JSON file and store them as well. I don't know where should I add the second process of reading JSON. I am very new to swift, anyone can give me some suggestions? thanks so much.

```
var posts: [Posts] = [Posts]()

@IBOutlet weak var theCollectionView: UICollectionView!
func getCategories(){

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/categories").responseJSON { (response) in
        if let jsonFile = response.result.value {

            var arrayOfPosts = [Posts]()

            for post in jsonFile as! NSArray {

                let postObj = Posts()

               // if !(post.valueForKeyPath("featured_image_thumbnail_url") is NSNull){

                  //  postObj.postThumbnailUrlString = post.valueForKeyPath("featured_image_thumbnail_url") as! String
                    postObj.postCategoryCode = "\(post.valueForKeyPath("id") as! NSNumber)"
                    postObj.theDictionary = post.valueForKeyPath("_links") as! NSDictionary
                    postObj.theCategoryArray = (postObj.theDictionary.valueForKeyPath("wp:post_type") as? NSArray)!
                    postObj.postCategoryListUrl = postObj.theCategoryArray[0].valueForKeyPath("href") as! String

                    arrayOfPosts.append(postObj)



            }

            self.posts = arrayOfPosts
            self.theCollectionView.reloadData()


            }
        }
}

class Posts: NSObject{

var postTite:String = ""
var postContent: String = ""
var postCategoryCode: String = ""
var postThumbnailUrlString: String = ""
var theCategoryArray = NSArray()
var theDictionary = NSDictionary()
var postCategoryListUrl: String = ""  
}
```

I am using Alamofire, I tried add another loop after I got "postObj.postCategoryListUrl", but it didn't work. I need to use the url of "postObj.postCategoryListUrl" to read data of "postTitle", "postThumbnailUrlString" and "postContent". I am very new to swift, need some suggestions about this, thanks so much.

Comment: Do you need to reload your collection view from the second json? or where you want use the data from second json?

Comment: yes, I need to reload my collection view from the second JSON. I need to get all the data in the class Posts, and add them to the collection view. thanks

Comment: so you did not get all the post object from first json. right? other object of post will get from second josn? then you will reload collection view?

Comment: yes. I want to get the category from the first JSON and then use the url to get each post's detail from the second JSON, and reload all these data to the collection view. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Alamife.request for second json after this line

```
self.posts = arrayOfPosts
```

and when the second json data purse will complete then use this line.Then you will have complete post and post details.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
     self.theCollectionView.reloadData()
 })
```

Comment: for the new Alamofire.request(.GET, url), what is the url? self.posts.postCategoryListUrl? it didn't right. Sorry I am new to swift, still a little confused . thanks

Comment: and also, since I added the second request outside the first loop, I can use the same "postObj", so does that means I need to create another new var to store these data from JSON, and then put them to the "self.post" and then reload, is that right?

Comment: Glad to know. and sorry i was not at my pc. :)